# What's the name of the equation $- \Delta u + u = f$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, terminology

What's the name of the equation

$$- \Delta u + u = f?$$

(this is the non-homogenous case)

Comment: Inhomogeneous Helmholtz equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @RobertIsrael wrote in the comments, the equation you have just written looks very much as the inhomogeneous form of the Helmholtz equation. The Helmoltz equation is a simplified form of the wave equation. 
Wikipedia explains it well https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_equation